# The requested content does not exist of SPA deployed as Azure Blob Static Website with CDN and V-Net

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage, azure-virtual-network, azure-cdn

I have a SPA (built with angular) and deployed to Azure Blob Storage. Everything works fine and well with azure CDN. ones I put azure storage in to the azure sub net inside azure V-net storage, CDN url gives 'The requested content does not exist' but default url (storage url) works fine.

Comment: CDN and Azure blob storage are two different things. what do you mean by CDN url?

Comment: ones I host the app in storage I'm getting a default site URL , and I create a CDN endpoint and configure it in azure CDN, then I'm getting a CDN end point URL

Answer (score 2):

From your description, It looks like you have allowed access from selected networks in the `firewalls and virtual networks` of the storage account. Read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security).

> Turning on firewall rules for your storage account blocks incoming
>   requests for data by default, unless the requests originate from a
>   service operating within an Azure Virtual Network (VNet) or from
>   allowed public IP addresses. Requests that are blocked include those
>   from other Azure services, from the Azure portal, from logging and
>   metrics services, and so on.

So it will block the Azure CDN request when you access the SPA via CDN endpoint. In this case, if you want to allow the access from your Azure CDN, you could [retrieve the current POP IP list for Azure CDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-pop-list-api) and then whitelist these IP ranges in the firewall of your storage account.

Comment: I used verizon premium CDN and do I need to whitelist  all the CDN pop ips (I think 50+)

Comment: CDN is a global service, but I think you can filter the IPs with the region that close to your end user.

Comment: Thank you I'll try to whitelist all the IPs and let you know the progress.

Comment: any process in this question?